# Producing Empty TKinter GUIs

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

The following TKinter code is producing an empty TK window. I cannot figure out why. I am packing everything appropriately. The map is the first Frame that is supposed to come up but when it launches there is only the top bar without any image or button. I also tried launching the hydra level frame first and it produces the same results.

```
#class inspired by sentdex SeaOfBTCapp
#see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A0gaXfM1UN0&index=2&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDclKx-QpC9wntnURXVJqLyk
class GUI_Control(Tk):
    def __init__(self, player, control, *args, **kwargs):
        self.player = player
        self.delegate = control
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.window = Frame(self)
        self.window.pack()

        #specify frames that can be loaded into the TK window. These will be defined in subclasses of Tk.Frame
        self.frames = {}

        #setup initial frame, all frames take GUI_Control as a listener to control event handling with window changes
        level_keys = [Map, Hydra_Level]
        for level in level_keys:
            frame = level(self.window, self)
            self.frames[level] = frame

        self.show(Map)



    #show the frame from the dictionary in the tkinter window
    def show(self, controller):
        frame = self.frames[controller]
        print(isinstance(frame, Frame))
        frame.tkraise()

    def open(self):
        self.mainloop()

    def switch(self):
        pass


class Map(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, controller, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.controller = controller
        # define map gui here
        self.map_picture = PhotoImage(file=r"images/archipelago.gif")
        self.image = Label(self, image=self.map_picture)
        self.image.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        self.go_to_button = Button(self, text="Go to", command=lambda: self.controller.show(Hydra_Level))
        self.go_to_button.pack()


class Hydra_Level(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, controller, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.listener = master
        self.go_to_button = Button(self, text="Back to map", command=lambda: self.controller.show(Map))
        self.go_to_button.grid(row=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am packing everything appropriately

No, you are not. You aren't calling `pack`, `place` or `grid` on `the`Map`or`Hydra` objects.